# Multiple Columns, way to select closest to a value

Tags: matlab, variables, average

I'm trying to analyze data sets that are obtained from CSV files.  After the data is read into matlab, I am left with a variable of my data only.  The number of columns and rows changes between each file.  Is there a way to average each column and then create a variable for the one with the closest average to a certain value? and then also select the columns directly before and after this middle column and create variables for them, as well as create a variable for the column with the lowest average?  Currently, I am selecting the columns manually and creating a variables for them that way.

For example:

I have this table of numbers.  (I used the same number in each column for sake of easy averaging in this example.

```
    1     2     3     4     5     

    1     2     3     4     5

    1     2     3     4     5

    1     2     3     4     5

    1     2     3     4     5
```

Let's say I want the column whose average is closest to 3.2

That column would be column 3 whose average is 3.  Then I would want the code to select the column before (column 2) and the column after (column 4).  As well as the column with the lowest average (column 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the averages (I assume the data matrix is in variable X):

```
Xmns = mean(X);
```

Then to find the minimum, use "min":

```
[val,ind] = min(Xmns);
```

"val" holds the minimum value, "ind" the corresponding index in Xmns, which is the corresponding column.

To find the column mean closest to a particular value, again you can use min:

```
[val,ind] = min(abs(Xmns-key_val));
```

Now "ind" holds the column index with mean closest to "key_val".  The next column is just "ind+1" and the previous "ind-1" - just be sure to check you are not beyond the ends of the matrix (i.e. ind may already be 1 or size(X,2)).

Also, given the column index "ind", to create a new variable with that column, you just use:

```
sc= X(:,ind);
```

and if you want to remove that column from X:

```
X(:,ind) = [];
```

and that is all.